# Inverting a bitmap in Embarcadero C++Builder

Tags: image, c++builder, timage, scanline

The same problem happens in Borland C++Builder 6 and Embarcadero C++Builder 2010.

When I try to invert an image, the form freezes for about 5 seconds and nothing happens. When I click again, the image is inverted within a blink of an eye, and again, again...

To reproduce, create a form with a `TImage` and two `TButton`'s using this code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <jpeg.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
#include "Unit1.h"
TForm1 *Form1;
Graphics::TBitmap *CurrentBitmap;
bool bLoaded = false;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner) {
    CurrentBitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool __fastcall Invert( TImage *img ) {
    if( bLoaded ) {
        double Scale, ScaleW, ScaleH;
        Graphics::TBitmap *bmp = new Graphics::TBitmap;
        bmp->Assign( CurrentBitmap );
        DWORD **pixel = new DWORD*[bmp->Height];
        for( long y=0; y<bmp->Height; y++ ) {
            pixel[y] = (DWORD*)(bmp->ScanLine[y]);
            for( long x=0; x<bmp->Width; x++ ) {
                if( pixel[y][x] == clBlack ) {
                    pixel[y][x] = clWhite;
                } else if( pixel[y][x] == clWhite ) {
                    pixel[y][x] = clBlack;
                }
            }

        }
        delete[] pixel;
        ScaleW = (double)bmp->Width / img->ClientWidth;
        ScaleH = (double)bmp->Height / img->ClientHeight;
        if( ScaleW > ScaleH ) {
            Scale = ScaleW;
        } else {
            Scale = ScaleH;
        }
        CurrentBitmap->Assign( bmp );
        img->Picture->Bitmap->Canvas->StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, bmp->Width/Scale, bmp->Height/Scale), bmp );
        delete bmp;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
    TJPEGImage *jpg = new TJPEGImage();
    jpg->LoadFromFile( "V:\\CBuilder\\BCB10\\GerberTest\\Testdata\\GerberTest.dpi2400.mskcmp.jpg" );
    CurrentBitmap->Width = jpg->Width;
    CurrentBitmap->Height = jpg->Height;
    CurrentBitmap->Canvas->StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, jpg->Width, jpg->Height), jpg );
    bLoaded = true;
    double Scale, ScaleW, ScaleH;
    ScaleW = (double)jpg->Width / Image1->ClientWidth;
    ScaleH = (double)jpg->Height / Image1->ClientHeight;
    if( ScaleW > ScaleH ) {
        Scale = ScaleW;
    } else {
        Scale = ScaleH;
    }
    Image1->Canvas->StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, jpg->Width/Scale, jpg->Height/Scale), jpg );
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender) {
    Invert( Image1 );
}
```

I cannot explain why the application freezes, or what the code is doing during the 5 second delay.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to learn how to use a **profiler** to determine where your code is actually spending its time. However, I will say that `Button1Click` is allocating new memory for the `CurrentBitmap` only the first time it is called, and then reusing that memory on subsequent calls.  And it is also leaking the `TJPEGImage` object...

Comment: ... `Invert()` is allocating a new `DWORD*[]` array that it doesn't actually need or use effectively. A single `DWORD*` pointing to the current `scanline` will suffice. And there is no need to copy `CurrentBitmap` to a temp `TBitmap` just to copy it back afterwards. You can just modify `CurrentBitmap` directly instead. And `Invert()` is assuming 32bit pixels are always being used, but your code is not doing anything to ensure that. You should set `PixelFormat=pf32bit` to force that.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, don't worry about the memory leak. I created a test application in 15 minutes to have a usable project for the invert function.
The invert function is part of a larger project and I wanted to keep it small and reproducible to post it here.
The use of a DWORD* pointer is a very good idea. I did not think of further optimizing after improving the running time from 5 seconds to 100ms :-)

Comment: The images I used for testing had 32bits pixels and I still don't understand why there is a delay (and no processing at all) when the pixel data are addressed as 8bit or 24bit or any size smaller than 32bits. I would expect a distorted image as a result of wrong handling of memory. 
I had already found the PixelFormat property and eliminated the delay. Also I had to use the Width and Height properties (even after an "Assign()" of pixel data) after I experienced the program crash with access violations on changing the pixels.

Comment: Being unsure of what I am doing, I execute these lines every time I start on a bitmap
```
bitmap->Width = <Width_of_the_source_image>;
bitmap->Height = <Height_of_the_source_image>;
bitmap->HandleType = bmDIB;
bitmap->PixelFormat = pf32bit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Remy Lebeau mentioned you should set the PixelFormat. I tried your solution which did not seems to invert images properly. Below you find a solution which should work properly.

```
#include <JPEG.hpp>

Byte __fastcall IntToByte(int AValue)
{
    if (AValue > 255)
        return 255;
    else if (AValue < 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return AValue;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall InvertBitmap(Graphics::TBitmap *ABitmap)
{
    Byte *p0;
    int red, green, blue;
    for (int y = 0; y < ABitmap->Height; y++) {
        p0 = (Byte*) ABitmap->ScanLine[y];
        for (int x = 0; x < ABitmap->Width; x++) {
            red = p0[x * 3];
            green = p0[x * 3 + 1];
            blue = p0[x * 3 + 2];

            // invert
            red = 255 - red;
            green = 255 - green;
            blue = 255 - blue;

            p0[x * 3] = IntToByte(red);
            p0[x * 3 + 1] = IntToByte(green);
            p0[x * 3 + 2] = IntToByte(blue);
        }
    }
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Screen->Cursor = crHourGlass;
    TJPEGImage *jpeg = new TJPEGImage();
    Graphics::TBitmap *bitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    try {
        jpeg->LoadFromFile("**YOUR-JPEG-FILE**");
        bitmap->SetSize(jpeg->Width, jpeg->Height);
        bitmap->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, jpeg);    
        bitmap->PixelFormat = pf24bit;
        InvertBitmap(bitmap);
        Image1->Picture->Bitmap->Assign(bitmap);
    }
    __finally {
        jpeg->Free();
        bitmap->Free();
    }
    Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Dmitri Luchtmeijer, Thank you for the code. I will have a look at it to see how much of it I can use. The pictures I have to invert are black and white. Addressing RGB data separately might not be necessary or even slower.... I will make up my mind later. :-)  Maybe its better to have one single universal invert function at hand for every image type.